# Postfix relay outgoing emails based on recipient

Tags: postfix, smtp, gmail, microsoft

I'm having trouble with Microsoft rejecting all our emails, I've contacted the Outlook.com Deliverability Support 3 times and 3 times they've told me that there's no problem with our IP and that I should join the Smart Network Data Services (SNDS) program and the Junk Email Reporting Program (JMRP), which I've already done.

Is there any way to relay outgoing emails to outlook, msn, live, etc... to gmail to send from a temporary address until we can fix this problem?

I've seen relayhost and transport_maps but I'm not sure if I can use wildcards there.

---

Also if you have had this problem with Microsoft I'm also interested in hearing any solution you may have.

Comment: Do you get an NDR (Non Delivery Report) for the emails - the answer is probably in there.  If you don't understand why it should fail then please post here.

Comment: The exact message is
```
<email@hotmail.com>: host
    hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.1.33] said: 550 5.7.1
    Unfortunately, messages from [MY_IP] weren't sent. Please contact
    your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block
    list (S3150). You can also refer your provider to
    http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.
    [VE1EUR01FT021.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com] (in reply to MAIL
    FROM command)
```

Comment: Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@example.net header.s=default header.b=WDkhjrD0;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning admin@example.net does not designate xx.xx.xx.xx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=admin@example.net;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=example.net

This is sent from W10 Mail connected using IMAP4 to the postfix server xx.xx.xx.xx to a gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

OK - so that means that the IP address you are sending from is on their block list. You have probably already found something like this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/since-part-of-their-network-is-on-our-block-list/d956ad0e-3019-4440-bbb1-15693d66e438 already. You can find lots of sites that will do "IP Quality" checks, and it's wiorht using those to check if other lists have downgraded your IP. Perhaps start with spamhouse and then google for others until you find the lists you are on.  Normally there will be an explanation of why you are on the lsit so you can then fix that to be removed from the list.

Comment: I've already checked dnsbl.info, dnschecker.org/ip-blacklist-checker.php and mxtoolbox.com.
They only show spamrat as having us listed but then spamrats says they don't.
I've contacted Outlook Sender Support but they say my ip is fine and to join those free programs.

Comment: In that article it refered to MS blocking an entire subnet - so if you're in a subnet that's blocked you may still have a problem.  You need to go back to them.  I know this is very frustrating but only MS can take whatever the block is off, or implement a whitelisting.

Comment: I'll message them to check the subnet, it's kind of amazing that's not the second step they do by themselves after checking that my IP is not blocked, instead of just emailing "All good here, join these programs".